# Inno Setup, get string from filename

Tags: filenames

I need get partial filename from file in ISPP...
Example file: {tmp}\myexefile-x.x.x.x-yyyyy.exe
I need get **x.x.x.x-yyyyy** string to defined variable

#define MyString "x.x.x.x-yyyyy"

Thanks and regards... ;-)